# I need to know how to pass variables in python as parameters on a program in windows

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, pyqt, ntlm-authentication

I started a little project to learn python, is a QT front-end for a desktop app that uses a 3rd party app to authenticate a user into a proxy system(cntlm), so I need to pass user and password(among other variables) as parameter to the cntlm. I've been searching a little bit but I get obfuscated with some codes as check_output methods and some other related, I don't get the real idea on how do this. Maybe there's somebody here that have an idea to do this kind of stuff. Thank you very much!. I'm sorry if a explain something wrong, it's my first question.

I tried the subprocess module but I don't get a good idea of which method is the good one for my situation

Comment: look at the `argparse` module https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: See: [Using QProcess to run external programs](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/qprocess-external-programs/) and [Qt5 Docs: QProcess](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).